# Any way to determine when your computer was last rebooted?

Tags: windows-7, logging, reboot

Is there an option in Windows that keeps track when your computer was last rebooted?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just run cmd.exe with this command

> systeminfo| find "System Boot Time"

For others solutions go to http://www.walkernews.net/2008/06/18/how-to-check-windows-last-boot-up-time/

Comment: That's a nice little command - I'll have to remember that one.

Comment: thats fantastic! i actually changed my Right Answer vote to this one because it was so much quicker! Sorry Matt - hope you don't mind. You got in quickest and your answer was right, but his is just so much easier

Comment: It's not accurate if your machine goes to sleep/hibernate.

Answer (score 3):

It will be in the event logs.

Fire up `Event Viewer` and select the `System` log from `Windows Logs` in the tree on the left.

There will be a lot of log entries in there, so click `Filter Current Log...` on the right and filter it for the `Kernel-General` log source only.

You will then find entries saying such things as:

```
The operating system started at system time ‎2011‎-‎03‎-‎09T00:04:30.375199800Z.
```

and

```
The operating system is shutting down at system time ‎2011‎-‎03‎-‎09T00:00:10.192212700Z.
```